# Has anyone got any code to call SignerSignEx from C#?

Tags: c#, cryptography, signed

Would really appreciate something that does the .Net equivalent of the SignerSignEx example here:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/alejacma/archive/2008/12/11/how-to-sign-exe-files-with-an-authenticode-certificate-part-2.aspx?CommentPosted=true

Thanks!!!!!!!

Comment: Why can't you just port the WScript/VB.NET examples you are given?

Comment: Because they use CAPICOM.dll and, as stated in my question, I want to use SignerSignEx.

Comment: (In case you haven't googled already, CAPICOM is a 32-bit COM-registered DLL, and I want a 64-bit solution that doesn't require regsrv32)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I got it working. If anyone's interested, here's the code - it probably needs a little more work to make it production-ready, but it works for me :)

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates;

namespace FingerPrinting.PatchUploader
{
    internal static class Signer
    {
        #region Structures

        [StructLayoutAttribute(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
        struct SIGNER_SUBJECT_INFO
        {
            public uint cbSize;
            public IntPtr pdwIndex;
            public uint dwSubjectChoice;
            public SubjectChoiceUnion Union1;
            [StructLayoutAttribute(LayoutKind.Explicit)]
            internal struct SubjectChoiceUnion
            {
                [FieldOffsetAttribute(0)]
                public System.IntPtr pSignerFileInfo;
                [FieldOffsetAttribute(0)]
                public System.IntPtr pSignerBlobInfo;
            }
        }

        [StructLayoutAttribute(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
        struct SIGNER_CERT
        {
            public uint cbSize;
            public uint dwCertChoice;
            public SignerCertUnion Union1;
            [StructLayoutAttribute(LayoutKind.Explicit)]
            internal struct SignerCertUnion
            {
                [FieldOffsetAttribute(0)]
                public IntPtr pwszSpcFile;
                [FieldOffsetAttribute(0)]
                public IntPtr pCertStoreInfo;
                [FieldOffsetAttribute(0)]
                public IntPtr pSpcChainInfo;
            };
            public IntPtr hwnd;
        }

        [StructLayoutAttribute(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
        struct SIGNER_SIGNATURE_INFO
        {
            public uint cbSize;
            public uint algidHash; // ALG_ID
            public uint dwAttrChoice;
            public IntPtr pAttrAuthCode;
            public IntPtr psAuthenticated; // PCRYPT_ATTRIBUTES
            public IntPtr psUnauthenticated; // PCRYPT_ATTRIBUTES
        }

        [StructLayoutAttribute(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
        struct SIGNER_FILE_INFO
        {
            public uint cbSize;
            public IntPtr pwszFileName;
            public IntPtr hFile;
        }

        [StructLayoutAttribute(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
        struct SIGNER_CERT_STORE_INFO
        {
            public uint cbSize;
            public IntPtr pSigningCert; // CERT_CONTEXT
            public uint dwCertPolicy;
            public IntPtr hCertStore;
        }
        #endregion

        #region Imports
        [DllImport("Mssign32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode, SetLastError = true)]
        private static extern int SignerSign(
            IntPtr pSubjectInfo,        // SIGNER_SUBJECT_INFO
            IntPtr pSignerCert,         // SIGNER_CERT
            IntPtr pSignatureInfo,      // SIGNER_SIGNATURE_INFO
            IntPtr pProviderInfo,       // SIGNER_PROVIDER_INFO
            string pwszHttpTimeStamp,   // LPCWSTR
            IntPtr psRequest,           // PCRYPT_ATTRIBUTES
            IntPtr pSipData            // LPVOID 
            );

        [DllImport("Mssign32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode, SetLastError = true)]
        private static extern int SignerTimeStamp(
            IntPtr pSubjectInfo,        // SIGNER_SUBJECT_INFO
            string pwszHttpTimeStamp,   // LPCWSTR
            IntPtr psRequest,           // PCRYPT_ATTRIBUTES
            IntPtr pSipData            // LPVOID 
            );

        [DllImport("Crypt32.DLL", EntryPoint = "CertCreateCertificateContext", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode, ExactSpelling = false, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
        private static extern IntPtr CertCreateCertificateContext(
            int dwCertEncodingType,
            byte[] pbCertEncoded,
            int cbCertEncoded);

        #endregion

        public static void Sign(string appPath, string thumbNail, string tsaServer)
        {
            var pSignerCert = IntPtr.Zero;
            var pSubjectInfo = IntPtr.Zero;
            var pSignatureInfo = IntPtr.Zero;
            try
            {
                pSignerCert = CreateSignerCert(thumbNail);
                pSubjectInfo = CreateSignerSubjectInfo(appPath);
                pSignatureInfo = CreateSignerSignatureInfo();

                SignCode(pSubjectInfo, pSignerCert, pSignatureInfo);

                if (tsaServer != null)
                {
                    TimeStampSignedCode(pSubjectInfo, tsaServer);
                }
            }
            finally
            {
                if (pSignerCert != IntPtr.Zero)
                {
                    Marshal.DestroyStructure(pSignerCert, typeof(SIGNER_CERT));
                }
                if (pSubjectInfo != IntPtr.Zero)
                {
                    Marshal.DestroyStructure(pSubjectInfo, typeof(SIGNER_SUBJECT_INFO));
                }
                if (pSignatureInfo != IntPtr.Zero)
                {
                    Marshal.DestroyStructure(pSignatureInfo, typeof(SIGNER_SIGNATURE_INFO));
                }
            }
        }

        private static IntPtr CreateSignerSubjectInfo(string pathToAssembly)
        {
            var info = new SIGNER_SUBJECT_INFO
            {
                cbSize = (uint)Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(SIGNER_SUBJECT_INFO)),
                pdwIndex = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(uint)))
            };
            var index = 0;
            Marshal.StructureToPtr(index, info.pdwIndex, false);

            info.dwSubjectChoice = 0x1; //SIGNER_SUBJECT_FILE
            var assemblyFilePtr = Marshal.StringToHGlobalUni(pathToAssembly);

            var fileInfo = new SIGNER_FILE_INFO
            {
                cbSize = (uint)Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(SIGNER_FILE_INFO)),
                pwszFileName = assemblyFilePtr,
                hFile = IntPtr.Zero
            };

            info.Union1 = new SIGNER_SUBJECT_INFO.SubjectChoiceUnion
            {
                pSignerFileInfo = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(SIGNER_FILE_INFO)))
            };

            Marshal.StructureToPtr(fileInfo, info.Union1.pSignerFileInfo, false);

            IntPtr pSubjectInfo = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(Marshal.SizeOf(info));
            Marshal.StructureToPtr(info, pSubjectInfo, false);

            return pSubjectInfo;
        }

        private static X509Certificate FindCertByThumbnail(string thumbnail)
        {
            try
            {
                var store = new X509Store(StoreName.TrustedPublisher, StoreLocation.LocalMachine);
                store.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly);
                var certs = store.Certificates.Find(X509FindType.FindByThumbprint, thumbnail, false);
                if (certs.Count == 0)
                {
                    throw new Exception(string.Format("Unable to find certificate with thumbnail '{0}'", thumbnail));
                }
                if (certs.Count > 1) // Can this happen?
                {
                    throw new Exception(string.Format("More than one certificate with thumbnail '{0}'", thumbnail));
                }
                store.Close();
                return certs[0];
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                throw new Exception(string.Format("Error locating certificate", e));
            }
        }

        private static IntPtr CreateSignerCert(string thumbNail)
        {
            var signerCert = new SIGNER_CERT
            {
                cbSize = (uint)Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(SIGNER_CERT)),
                dwCertChoice = 0x2,
                Union1 = new SIGNER_CERT.SignerCertUnion
                {
                    pCertStoreInfo = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(SIGNER_CERT_STORE_INFO)))
                },
                hwnd = IntPtr.Zero
            };

            const int X509_ASN_ENCODING = 0x00000001;
            const int PKCS_7_ASN_ENCODING = 0x00010000;

            var cert = FindCertByThumbnail(thumbNail);

            var pCertContext = CertCreateCertificateContext(
                X509_ASN_ENCODING | PKCS_7_ASN_ENCODING,
                cert.GetRawCertData(),
                cert.GetRawCertData().Length);

            var certStoreInfo = new SIGNER_CERT_STORE_INFO
            {
                cbSize = (uint)Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(SIGNER_CERT_STORE_INFO)),
                pSigningCert = pCertContext,
                dwCertPolicy = 0x2, // SIGNER_CERT_POLICY_CHAIN
                hCertStore = IntPtr.Zero
            };

            Marshal.StructureToPtr(certStoreInfo, signerCert.Union1.pCertStoreInfo, false);

            IntPtr pSignerCert = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(Marshal.SizeOf(signerCert));
            Marshal.StructureToPtr(signerCert, pSignerCert, false);

            return pSignerCert;
        }

        private static IntPtr CreateSignerSignatureInfo()
        {
            var signatureInfo = new SIGNER_SIGNATURE_INFO
            {
                cbSize = (uint)Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(SIGNER_SIGNATURE_INFO)),
                algidHash = 0x00008004, // CALG_SHA1
                dwAttrChoice = 0x0, // SIGNER_NO_ATTR
                pAttrAuthCode = IntPtr.Zero,
                psAuthenticated = IntPtr.Zero,
                psUnauthenticated = IntPtr.Zero
            };
            IntPtr pSignatureInfo = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(Marshal.SizeOf(signatureInfo));
            Marshal.StructureToPtr(signatureInfo, pSignatureInfo, false);

            return pSignatureInfo;
        }

        private static void TimeStampSignedCode(IntPtr pSubjectInfo, string tsaServer)
        {
            var hResult = SignerTimeStamp(
                pSubjectInfo,
                tsaServer,
                IntPtr.Zero,
                IntPtr.Zero
                );

            if (hResult != 0)
            {
                throw new Exception(string.Format("Error timestamping signed installer - Error code 0x{0:X}", hResult));
            }
        }

        private static void SignCode(IntPtr pSubjectInfo, IntPtr pSignerCert, IntPtr pSignatureInfo)
        {
            var hResult = SignerSign(
                pSubjectInfo,
                pSignerCert,
                pSignatureInfo,
                IntPtr.Zero,
                null,
                IntPtr.Zero,
                IntPtr.Zero
                );

            if (hResult != 0)
            {
                throw new Exception(string.Format("Error timestamping signed installer - Error code 0x{0:X}", hResult));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, This is not working for the signing of non executables. Can you please let me know how to sign a non executable?