# Code signing without signtool in C#

Tags: c#, .net-assembly, sign

Is there any way to sign an exe-File without the signtool.exe or sn.exe.

The reason is, I will sign by a highspeed program any call by ProcessInfo is to slow.

Comment: After calling signtool the first time it'll be in the disk cache memory, so calling it again will be very fast. The vast majority of the time will be used doing file I/O for the file being signed, so I can't see how anything would really be significantly faster than just calling sn.exe.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6357759/has-anyone-got-any-code-to-call-signersignex-from-c

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/26372061/722078