# how to manually sign an MSI file?

Tags: c#, .net, windows-installer, code-signing

Is it possible to sign an MSI file manually, without the signtool.exe tool that comes with the Windows SDK?

If so, how big of a job is this?

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: Why don't you want to use the standard tools for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure: [SignerSignEx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa387734.aspx) in C++; [wrapped in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6357759/89999). Unless you really mean manually, in which case get a binary editor, lots of paper, a good calculator, and don't make mistakes! :)